# How can I customize the scrolling path of a uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, scrollview

I want to use a horizontal scrolling in a UICollectionview similar to this picture below. How can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated. [image]

Comment: I think you need carousal instead of collectionView

Comment: I've checked iCarousel library and it doesnt have anything to give me a result like this :( https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: You need to implement UICollectionViewLayout methods to create your own custom layout. Refer to https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel on how to create custom layout.